# Ntfs.sys BSOD with page fault in non paged area

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ntfs, bsod

My laptop crashed with a BSOD with the message about ntfs.sys and "page fault in non paged area". The laptop runs on Windows 7. I tried to start a chckdsk command in several ways, but I cannot start a computer with the disk connected without a BSOD or the disk is not recognized.

1. I tried to boot in to safe mode with a command prompt, but also that ends in the same BSOD.
2. I tried to start the Windows recovery, both from the installation partition of the laptop and a Windows 7 installation DVD. But also that shows the same BSOD.
3. I tried to boot the Windows XP environment from the Hirens CD, that also shows the same BSOD.
4. I tried to boot the NTFS tools from the Hirens CD, that gives some error (don't know exactly wat).
5. I removed the harddisk and connected it to a working PC (also Windows 7) via a SATA-to-USB converter. When the disk is recognized by the computer, a BSOD occurs also noticing ntfs.sys and fault in non page area.
6. Finally i tried to boot a Knoppix live disk, knoppix does not see the hard driver.

Does anyone have any tips how the fix the hard drive, or if it is fixable at all?

Comment: The exact error you are seeing in hirens would be good to see.  Knoppix does not see the disk at all?  Try booting knoppix, and after it boots then attempt to connect the disk, and as root try to run mount -a.  Take a look at your /dev directory before you connect the drive, and then after you connect the drive to see if you see any new devices named /dev/sdXN where X = a-z and N = 1-9

Comment: It might be implicit, but... are you asking how to recover the files or how to repair your Windows installation?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to try to recover the data. A Windows re-install is fine but not necessary.

Comment: When I boot Knoppix Live without the hard disk and connect it later on, then the disk is recognised. Only when I  try to open the disk it notices: "NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!".

Comment: When I start NTFS4Dos and run chkdisk a part of the message is "Exception: 0E, Error code: 0006". Then a few lines some codes are shown it ends with "Info flags=00008026, Writing CW.ERR file..., CauseWay error 09: Unrecoverable exception. Program   terminated.". That is also the message when I run the chkdisk command myself.

Comment: did you ever fix this ?
i got same exact problem